# Compile error with ESP8266 SDK in KAA 0.10.0

Tags: esp8266, kaa

I have built the ESP8266 SDK according to [this document](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Using-Kaa-endpoint-SDKs/C/SDK-ESP8266/).

But the compile report shows the error below. Attachemnt is the ld file. Would you please help me to resolve it? Thanks a lot!

```
/opt/Espressif/crosstool-NG/builds/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld: esp8266_app section `.text' will not fit in region `iram1_0_seg'

/opt/Espressif/crosstool-NG/builds/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld: region `iram1_0_seg' overflowed by 43955 bytes

kaa/tools/kaa_encryption/rsa_key_gen/mbedtls/libmbedtls.a(entropy_poll.c.obj):(.text.mbedtls_platform_entropy_poll+0x8): undefined reference to `fopen'

kaa/tools/kaa_encryption/rsa_key_gen/mbedtls/libmbedtls.a(entropy_poll.c.obj):(.text.mbedtls_platform_entropy_poll+0xc): undefined reference to `fread'

kaa/tools/kaa_encryption/rsa_key_gen/mbedtls/libmbedtls.a(entropy_poll.c.obj):(.text.mbedtls_platform_entropy_poll+0x10): undefined reference to `fclose'

kaa/tools/kaa_encryption/rsa_key_gen/mbedtls/libmbedtls.a(entropy_poll.c.obj): In function `mbedtls_platform_entropy_poll':

entropy_poll.c:(.text.mbedtls_platform_entropy_poll+0x33): undefined reference to `fopen'

entropy_poll.c:(.text.mbedtls_platform_entropy_poll+0x48): undefined reference to `fread'

entropy_poll.c:(.text.mbedtls_platform_entropy_poll+0x56): undefined reference to `fclose'

entropy_poll.c:(.text.mbedtls_platform_entropy_poll+0x62): undefined reference to `fclose'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [esp8266_app] Error 1

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/esp8266_app.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Regards
Bobby

Answer (score 0):

To build the C SDK application correctly for the ESP8266 platform, disable the Encryption feature with `-DWITH_ENCRYPTION=OFF` CMake command line argument.

Furthermore, disable unused SDK extensions. For example, to disable the notification extension, you should pass the `-DWITH_EXTENSION_NOTIFICATION=OFF` to CMake. For more information about C SDK build configuration, see this file -- https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/blob/master/client/client-multi/client-c/CMakeLists.txt

Also, don't forget to pass the `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MinSizeRel` to CMake so that the resulting executable will be optimized for size.