# How to build the esp8266 with the Kaa sdk 0.10.1?

Tags: sdk, iot, kaa

I want to building the application with ESP8266, but some error with the barch 0.10.1 the error is

```
opt/Espressif/crosstool-NG/builds/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld: kaa_demo section '.irom0.text' will not fit in region `irom0_0_seg'

/opt/Espressif/crosstool-NG/builds/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld: region `irom0_0_seg' overflowed by 4964 bytes

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status `make2: * [kaa_demo] Error 1 make1: *[CMakeFiles/kaa_demo.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

could you give me some suggest to build is or tell me what the vison can build with the ESP8266.

Answer (score 1):

According to second line: `region irom0_0_seg overflowed by 4964 bytes`

1- This message said that specified space is not enough; And you need to increase the space.

2- Also you can see below link:

[Compile error with ESP8266 SDK in KAA 0.10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327054/compile-error-with-esp8266-sdk-in-kaa-0-10-0)

Basically, there are two sections where code can be placed. 
The first one is the .text section, which maps to the iram segment, and another one is the .irom0.text section, which maps to the irom segment.

The issue is that there is not enough space to place the Kaa SDK code in the iram segment  (the .text section is mapped to the iram segment by default) .

This is why the default SDK linker scripts are modified to force linking the Kaa SDK code to the irom segment.